# Column splitting into groups using pig latin

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I have a table with two columns (code:chararray, sp:double)

I want to divide the second field sp into different groups (for example  based on condition like (<25),(>25 <45),(>=45).

INPUT

```
code sp
t001 60.0
t001 75.0
a003 34.0
t001 60.0
a003 23.0
a003 23.0
t001 45.0
t001 10.0
t001 8.0
a003 20.0
t001 38.0
a003 55.0
a003 50.0
t001 08.0
a003 44.0
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
code    bin1     bin2        bin3
       (<25)   (>25 <45)    >=45
t001    3          1          4 
a003    3          2          2
```

I am trying the script like below:

```
data = LOAD 'Sandy/rd.csv' using PigStorage(',') As (code:chararray,sp:double);

data2 = DISTINCT data;

selfiltnew = FOREACH data2 generate code, sp;
group_new = GROUP selfiltnew by (code,sp);

newselt = FOREACH group_new GENERATE selfiltnew.code AS code,selfiltnew.sp AS sp;

bin1 = filter newselt by sp < 25.0;
grp1 = FOREACH bin1 GENERATE newselt.code AS code, COUNT(newselt.sp) AS (sp1:double);

bin2 = filter newselt by sp < 45 and sp >= 25;
grp2 = FOREACH bin3 GENERATE newselt.code AS code, COUNT(newselt.sp) AS (sp2:double);

bin3 = filter newselt by sp >=75;
grp3 = FOREACH bin3 GENERATE newselt.code AS code, COUNT(newselt.sp) AS (sp3:double);

newbin = JOIN grp1 by code,grp2 by code,grp3 by code;

newtable = FOREACH newbin GENERATE grp1::group.code AS code, SUM(sp1) AS bin1,SUM(sp2) AS bin2,SUM(sp3) AS bin3;

data2 = FOREACH newtable GENERATE code, bin1, bin2, bin3;
dump newtable;
```

How can i get the correct output using pig latin?

Comment: Please specify what's wrong with your script, what do you get instead of the expected result

Comment: @YakovL -- Error is coming at the grp1 = FOREACH bin1 GENERATE newselt.code AS code, COUNT(newselt.sp) AS (sp1:double); Here I want to calculate the count of all those sp, who falls below 25.  I am getting the following error: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.COUNT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: I am not sure, whether this logic is good. Is there any best solutions to split into bins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing your desired output no `DISTINCT` is needed. Also there's no need to perform some of the steps you are following. Note that if the source is separated by a space you should use  `PigStorage(' ')` instead of `PigStorage(',')`
Following what @inquisitive_mind pointed, the code would be as follows:

```
data = LOAD 'Sandy/rd.csv' using PigStorage(' ') As (code:chararray,sp:double);
bin1 = filter data by sp < 25.0;
grouped1 = GROUP bin1 by code;
grp1 = FOREACH grouped1 GENERATE group AS code, COUNT(bin1.sp) AS (sp1:double);
bin2 = filter data by (sp >= 25.0 AND sp<45);
grouped2 = GROUP bin2 by code;
grp2 = FOREACH grouped2 GENERATE group AS code, COUNT(bin2.sp) AS (sp2:double);
bin3 = filter data by sp >= 45.0;
grouped3 = GROUP bin3 by code;
grp3 = FOREACH grouped3 GENERATE group AS code, COUNT(bin3.sp) AS (sp3:double);
result= JOIN grp1 BY code, grp2 by code, grp3 by code;
final_result = FOREACH result GENERATE grp1::code as code, grp1::sp1 as bin1, grp2::sp2 as bin2, grp3::sp3 as bin3;
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What about Inner JOIN. If any of grp1, grp2 or grp3 has zero itms, final output it coming zero. Which join to use? In my actual dataset, I am having almost six grps and there is a possibility of zero items in any of the groups.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GROUP BY before using COUNT

**Source:** [COUNT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#COUNT)
*Usage

Use the COUNT function to compute the number of elements in a bag. COUNT requires a preceding GROUP ALL statement for global counts and a GROUP BY statement for group counts.*

```
bin1 = filter newselt by sp < 25.0;
grouped1 = GROUP bin1 by (newselt.code);
grp1 = FOREACH grouped1 GENERATE group AS code, COUNT(newselt.sp) AS (sp1:double);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.